# Response not successful: Received status code 400 at new ApolloError

Tags: next.js, graphql, nestjs, apollo, apollo-server

I am working on an application with has the backend NestJS with graphql and postgres. Front End is in Next JS. Facing an error while calling a mutation from the front end.

Only one of the mutations are working via Code(Find at the last).

Relevant details of the code are below:

--- Graphql Query definition ---
Front End Code:

```
const SAVE_PASSWORD_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation SavePassword($passwordInput: Password!, $userId: Float!) {
    savePassword(passwordInput: $passwordInput, userId: $userId) {
      email
      username
      # Other user fields
    }
  }
`;
```

--- handle submit function ---

```
const handleSubmit = async (value: any) => {
    try {
      const response = await savePassword({
        variables: {
          passwordInput: {
            password: "hyperx",
            confirmPassword: "hyperx",
          },
          userId: 2, // Replace with the actual user ID
        },
      });

      console.log('Password saved:', response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving password:', error);
    }
    console.log(value);
    // dispatch(updatePassword(value.password))
    // dispatch(updateFormName("registration"))
  }
```

Front End Configuration:

```
"use client";

import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  HttpLink,
  SuspenseCache,
} from "@apollo/client";
import {
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";

function makeClient() {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    // https://studio.apollographql.com/public/splacex-l4uc6p/
    uri: "http://localhost:3006/graphql",
  });

  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link:
      typeof window === "undefined"
        ? ApolloLink.from([
          new SSRMultipartLink({
            stripDefer: true,
          }),
          httpLink,
        ])
        : httpLink,
  });
}

// also has a function to create a suspense cache
function makeSuspenseCache() {
  return new SuspenseCache();
}

export default function ApolloWrapper({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  return (
    <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient= { makeClient }  >
    { children }
    </ ApolloNextAppProvider>
  );
}
```

---layout.tsx---
Backend Code:

```
import './globals.css';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar';
import Footer from '@/components/Footer';
import ReduxProvider from '@/features/Provider';
import ApolloWrapper from '@/lib/apollo-wrapper';
const inter = Inter({
  weight: ["200", "400", "500"],
  subsets: ['latin'],
});

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Customer Portal',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};



export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const navAndFotterHidingRoute = ["/dashboard"];


  return (
    // <Provider store={store}>
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ReduxProvider>
          <Navbar navAndFotterHidingRoute={navAndFotterHidingRoute} />
          <ApolloWrapper>
            {children}
          </ApolloWrapper>
        </ReduxProvider>

        <Footer navAndFotterHidingRoute={navAndFotterHidingRoute} />
      </body>
    </html>
    // </Provider>
  );
}
```

Backend Code:
---Mutation copied from schema file---

```
savePassword(passwordInput: Password!, userId: Float!): User!
```

---Input type Password---

```
input Password {
  password: String!
  confirmPassword: String!
}
```

---Resolver Function---

```
@Mutation(() => User)
  async savePassword(
    @Args('passwordInput') passwordInput: Password,
    @Args('userId') userId: number,
  ): Promise<User> {
    console.log(passwordInput, userId)
    return this.userService.savePassword(passwordInput, userId);
  }
```

--- Postman Request and Response ---
[image]

-- Only working API --

```
const SEND_OTP_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation SendOTP($email: String!) {
      sendOTP(email: $email)
    }
  `;
```

Comment: It's a bad request that you're sending to the backend. Did you send a request with `curl` or Postman? Was it successful?

Comment: Thanks for the Response @GolamrabbiAzad. Yes, I have also pasted the screenshot of the Postman request and response by editing the answer. Also, one mutation is working fine. All the others are giving the same error. I have also pasted the code for the working mutation which is working via code.

Comment: one mutation working means it's a great sign that your front-end client can talk to the backend. Now, double-check the data front-end sending through the `fetch` API, with cache style `getClient().query({ query })` for RSC or  `useSuspenseQuery(query)` for the client component.

Comment: Thanks, @GolamrabbiAzad, it helped. I logged my mutation before consuming it and copy-pasted the same on the GraphQL playground. username was not a field in the entity.

Comment: That's why it's a BAD_REQUEST_400. Anyway, It was great chatting with you! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems accidentally username field was added when I am actually using email as the username. Found this by using the following code:

```
const [savePassword, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(SAVE_PASSWORD_MUTATION);
  // Log the GraphQL query
  console.log("GraphQL Query:", SAVE_PASSWORD_MUTATION?.loc?.source?.body);
```

This gave me my mutation being run which I pasted on GraphQL playground. It showed me my error that I don't have username as a field in my entity